# html h1 tag no show type

Tags: python, html, django

after click no.1 and blank to than page it no show h1 tag

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DIAL.png)

inspect here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKT5d.png)

code html here

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{room.name}}</h1>

{% endblock content %}
```

code python here i don't know this have problem or not

```
from django.shortcuts import render

rooms = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Lets learn python!'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Design with me!'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Fronted develpoers!'},
]


def home(request):
    context = {'rooms': rooms}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)


def room(request, pk):
    room = None
    for i in rooms:
        if i['id'] == int(pk):
            room = i
    context = {'romm': room}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misspelled `room` context.

Instead of this:

```
<h1>{{room.name}}</h1>
```

Try this:

```
<h1>{{romm.name}}</h1>
```